# Errors were encountered while processing issue

Tags: wine, dpkg

When trying to install wine, I got the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing package libsasl2-modules:i386 (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
libssl1.1:amd64
libssl1.1:i386
libsasl2-modules:amd64
libsasl2-modules:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can someone help me fix this?
i did

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

output:

```
dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege
```

doing:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

did:

```
Setting up libssl1.1:i386 (1.1.0e-1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by  
another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package libssl1.1:i386 (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit 
status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libsasl2-
modules:amd64:
libsasl2-modules:amd64 depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0); however:
Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libsasl2-modules:amd64 (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libsasl2-
modules:i386:
libsasl2-modules:i386 depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0); however:
Package libssl1.1:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libsasl2-modules:i386 (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
libssl1.1:i386
libsasl2-modules:amd64
libsasl2-modules:i386
```

did:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a --force-depends
```

output:

```
Setting up libssl1.1:i386 (1.1.0e-1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by 
another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package libssl1.1:i386 (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit 
status 1
dpkg: libsasl2-modules:i386: dependency problems, but configuring 
anyway as you requested:
libsasl2-modules:i386 depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0); however:
Package libssl1.1:i386 is not configured yet.

Setting up libsasl2-modules:i386 (2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-2) ...
dpkg: libsasl2-modules:amd64: dependency problems, but configuring 
anyway as you requested:
libsasl2-modules:amd64 depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0); however:
Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

Setting up libsasl2-modules:amd64 (2.1.27~101-g0780600+dfsg-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
libssl1.1:i386
```

i did:

```
sudo fuser -v -k /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
```

output:

```
USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/var/cache/debconf/config.dat:
                 root      16901 F.... dpkg-preconfigu
```

now it says:

```
dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process
```

but wine seems to have installed

Comment: Try `dpkg --configure -a` and [edit] your question with the output.

Comment: Well, go with `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Run `sudo fuser -v -k /var/cache/debconf/config.dat` and post the output

Comment: Now do `sudo kill 16901 & sudo kill -9 16901` and try `sudo dpkg --configure -a --force-depends` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we can read from

```
dpkg: error processing package libsasl2-modules:i386 (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

**1.** **You have to run**

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

Which gave us

```
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by  
another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

**2.** So in order to unlock `/var/cache/debconf/config.dat`:

```
sudo fuser -v -k /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
```

or run

```
sudo fuser -v /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
```

and kill the process using the given PID, such as:

`sudo kill PID_HERE & sudo kill -9 PID_HERE`

---

Now after that, `dpkg --configure -a` should be able to solve the issue, if not, try with `sudo dpkg --configure -a --force-depends`.

---

Sources & further information:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dpkg.1.html

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/fuser.1.html

Comment: Thank you, this works!